# Not Able to send the mail on mailId which have numeric value, Its giving error : No recipients have been specified

Tags: email, mailkit

Eg. Anooppandey3@gmail.com

System.InvalidOperationException: No recipients have been specified.

at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.Send(FormatOptions options, MimeMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ITransferProgress progress)

at MailKit.MailTransport.Send(MimeMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ITransferProgress progress)

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 1 address to be added to the message's `To`, `Cc` or `Bcc` properties.

Comment: Use `message.WriteTo (fileName);` to write it out to a text file, then paste the headers in your question so we can take a look at why you do not have any recipients specified.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the latest MailKit. Are you using an old version of MailKit, perhaps?